# Linq query, select inner query into list?

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am writing a linq query to select a blogpost,

```
    from data in dataContext.Blog_BlogPosts
        join tagsData in dataContext.Blog_TagToPostConnections on data.BlogPostID equals tagsData.BlogPostID
        where data.Slug == "asp-programmering"
        select new BlogPost
        {
            Title = data.Title,
            Slug = data.Slug,
            Author = data.Author,
            Text = data.Text,
            Tags = (from tags in dataContext.Blog_Tags where tags.TagID == tagsData.TagID select new Tag { TagID = tags.TagID, TagName = tags.Tag }).ToList()
        };
```

The blogpost class looks like this (used to test it)

```
    public class BlogPost
    {
        public string Slug { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public DateTime Published { get; set; }
        public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    }
```

The blogpost i am testing got 3 tags attached to it. The table structure is:

(table)BlogPost -> (table)BlogPostTags <- (table)Tags

So the BlogPostTags table only contains 2 fields, BlogPostID and TagID.

When i run the query above i get 3 results back. Same blogpost 3 times but with 1 tag in each. It should return 1 post with 3 tags. The problem lies in the Tags query above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are joining on `Blog_TagToPostConnections` in the outer expression. Since there are three matching tags, the join will produce three result items. Move the join into the expression being assigned to `Tags` (that's where you *want* three things to pop out).

```
from data in dataContext.Blog_BlogPosts
    where data.Slug == "asp-programmering"
    select new BlogPost
    {
        Title = data.Title,
        Slug = data.Slug,
        Author = data.Author,
        Text = data.Text,
        Tags = (from tags in dataContext.Blog_Tags
                join tagsData in dataContext.Blog_TagToPostConnections
                     on tags.TagID equals tagsData.TagID
                where data.BlogPostID == tagsData.BlogPostID
                select new Tag { TagID = tags.TagID, TagName = tags.Tag }
               ).ToList()
    };
```